nmcli not showing connections
I am new to linux and was trying to configure me system, I wanted to use https://github.com/ericmurphyxyz/rofi-wifi-menu, but saw it was not showing any connections.
When I enter nmcli I get this
lo: connected (externally) to lo
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
        inet4 127.0.0.1/8
        inet6 ::1/128

enp2s0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), B4:45:06:D9:65:B5, hw, mtu 1500

wlp3s0: unavailable
        "Realtek RTL8821CE"
        wifi (rtw_8821ce), 9A:98:C1:92:6D:79, hw, mtu 1500

And entering nmcli device wifi list I get:
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 

Entering nmcli con:
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
lo                  66a00c43-8262-495a-a808-19daa15176e2  loopback  lo     
Wired connection 1  ca90b794-139c-36fd-a248-3ca5b1b4602b  ethernet  -- 

Entering nmcli con show wlp3s0:
Error: wlp3s0 - no such connection profile.

A thing to note is my laptop is connected to the wifi and can access the internet, and I connected to the wifi during the installation of Debian. And when I restart NeworkManager it doesn't reconnect to the wifi unless I reboot
I'll gladly provide any more info for help
Edit:
I have not made anychanges to the network settings since installation. Also now on some boots I don't have wifi, only after a few reboots do I connect.
Adding a connection with nmcli con add, I now get the output from nmcli con show:
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
lo                  051be556-c06e-4a8f-ad7c-9fb29f276ba9  loopback  lo     
wifi                16ab3681-5062-4d1c-be34-be6f41cefd29  wifi      --     
Wired connection 1  ca90b794-139c-36fd-a248-3ca5b1b4602b  ethernet  --     


Thanks

Add the output of nmcli con and nmcli con show wlp3s0 to the question. Do not post it in the comments.

@NasirRiley done

What is the OS? Is there another network management service running on the system? Have you tried adding and configuring the wireless interface via nmcli con add?

@NasirRiley I don't think I have other managers installed. How do I check? I added a connection with nmcli con add, and added the new connection list above. Sorry for my lack of knowledge with these things, I am very new to linux

Your connection called wifi does not have a device and hence isn't managed by NetworkManager. Did you add one? If not, add the device wlp3s0 to the connection see if it works.

Hi, sorry for the late response I have been looking at my system for a bit and found a different manager running, it now works as intended. Thanks for the help!

I rolled back an edit where you added "SOLVED" to the question title.  If you have found a solution to your issue, then please consider leaving it in an answer using the answer box at the bottom of the page.  You may later accept your own answer.  An accepted answer markets the issue as resolved. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Turns out I had another network manager running, , I simply uninstalled ifupdown and removed ifupdown from plugins in network manager config file:
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

